# Two lists of different custom types to be passed in the same method as an argument

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, lombok

I have two Classes like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooCounts {
    private Long countOfRows;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DooCounts {
    private Long countOfRows;
}
```

I created two Lists of the above types and did the following:

```
List<FooCounts> fooCounts = ...; //initialisation doesn't matter
List<DooCounts> dooCounts = ...;
Long countOfRows = 0L;

if(!fooCounts.isEmpty){
    countOfRows = fooCounts.map(FooCounts::getCountOfRows).sum().longValue();
}

if(!dooCounts.isEmpty){
    countOfRows = dooCounts.map(DooCounts::getCountOfRows).sum().longValue();
}
```

Is it possible to make these two 'if' blocks as one 'if' block by creating a method out of it? I mean something like this:

```
private Long fooDooCounts(List<T> fooDooCounts) {
if(!fooDooCounts.isEmpty){
    countOfRows = fooDooCounts.map(fooDooCounts::getCountOfRows).sum().longValue();
}
```

Comment: Sure, if you implement a shared interface.

Comment: What Louis meant is something like `interface CanCountRows{ Long countOfRows(); }` Now both of your classes should `... implements CanCountRows {...}`. This way your generic method can be declared as `private <T extends CanCountRows> Long fooDooCounts(List<T> list){ ... }` and it can accept List<FooCounts> and List<DooCounts>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is strictly namespaced. The *name* of a method/field are relevant only insofar as that they exist in the context of a type (hence, in java you can't define fields or methods outside of a type - because names do not mean anything outside of them), and the name of a type is only meaningful in light of the package it is in.

In other words, the actual name of string's toLowerCase method is `java.lang.String::toLowerCase`.

There is no way in java to say 'I want to call the toLowerCase method on this object, whatever the type of the object is, regardless of where the method comes from. Long as it is called toLowerCase, call it'. It just doesn't exist. You can see this in action in class files, where any invocation is necessarily always bound up with a fully qualified name (it would look like `java/lang/String toLowerCase()Ljava/lang/String;` in classfile-ese, but it's the same principle, just in classfile form).

There's a good reason for this.

Imagine these two types:

```
interface Gun {
  void shoot(Person p);
}

interface Camera {
  void shoot(Person p);
}
```

hopefully this illustrates the subtle but serious dangers of allowing you to write, in a programming language 'just call `shoot(p)` on this object, whatever it might be, if it has a shoot method, go for it'.

Hence, 'can you write code in java that fetches a field of a given name, regardless of what type the objects are, as long as it has a field of some name, just get the data out of it' - the answer is a very very simple: No, you can't, and you don't want to - that is not how java is designed to work, and going against the 'grain' of how a language wants to be used results in all sorts of maintenance headaches.

Fortunately, it also gives you the strategy to fix the problem: Ensure that the 'fetch operation' **is** the same fully qualified name. How do we do that? By introducing a type that unifies the definition of what `countOfRows` means, and then have your various classes implement it:

```
interface RowCounter {
  long countRows();
}
```

Now we have a uniform definition. You can stick docs on this if you want. Then it is simply a matter of implementing it in your types:

```
class FooCount implements RowCounter {
  @Override public long countRows() {
    return countOfRows;
  }
}
```

Because now the `countRows` method in your `FooCount` class is in fact just a more specific implementation of `RowCounter::countRows`, the fully qualified name of that method is `com.pkg.RowCounter::countRows`. Thus, you can now invoke it:

```
long sum(List<? extends RowCounter> rowCounters) {
  long totalCount = 0;
  for (var r : rowCounters) totalCount += rowCounters.countRows();
  return totalCount;
}
```

and you can pass a list of FooCounter objects, or a list of BarCounter, or a list of RowCounter, etc.